# Find $\lim \ a_n$ if $a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+n}}.$

Tags: calculus, limits

I would greatly appreciate some help in finding $\lim \ a_n$ if
$$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+n}}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**:

Note that $$\dfrac1{\sqrt[3]{n^3+n}} \leq \dfrac1{\sqrt[3]{n^3+k}} \leq \dfrac1{\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}}$$
for all $k \in \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$.

Hence,
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt[3]{1+1/n^2}} = \dfrac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+n}} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac1{\sqrt[3]{n^3+k}} \leq \dfrac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}} = \dfrac1{\sqrt[3]{1+1/n^3}}$$

Now apply the squeeze/sandwich theorem.